# Who sells RP-1 to SpaceX and other commercial launch companies?

Tags: launch, rockets

I read a question on Quora that seemed too simple to not find an answer through Google. Alas, it seems RP-1 is rare enough that there isn't more information than "vendors that sell to NASA" for who supplies RP-1 for rocket launches. I would imagine its Shell or Exxon, but it doesn't say. Since its a hydrocarbon, I would imagine its a private company, and that its not refined on-site at the spaceport, but I may be wrong.

So which company sells RP-1 to companies that launch rockets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the problem is that RP-1 is a very generic abbreviation. When you add the actual standard that RP-1 must comply with ([MIL_DTL_25576](http://propellants.ksc.nasa.gov/commodities/specs/MIL_DTL_25576D.pdf)), the search results get more specific.

These are the first two companies I found that sell RP-1:

- [Shell](https://www.shell.com/content/dam/shell/static/aviation/downloads/AeroShell-Book/aeroshell-book-10busspecs.pdf)
- [Haltermann solutions](http://www.haltermannsolutions.com/fueltypes/aerospace)

(there are probably more, but you get the general idea now)